# How to get Blurtooth on a PI 4

Tags: bluetooth

I tried this to get Bluetooth set up on my PI4 with no luck
Terminal
From the Raspberry Pi desktop, open a new Terminal window.
Type sudo bluetoothctl then press enter and input the administrator password (the default password is raspberry).
Next, enter agent on and press enter. ...
Type scan on and press enter one more time. ...
To pair the device, type pair [device Bluetooth address].
It came up with all those numbers which meant nothing to me.
Why are you all so unhelpful on here.
I am deleting my account.

Comment: Did you [read any of these?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=bluetooth+tty)

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `sudo` with `bluetoothctl`. You should be able to use `pi` user. What is your question? Maybe you need to update your question with information about what device you are trying to connect to. What you are expect to happen and what is actually happening. It would also be useful if you shared what those numbers are that it came up with. To me it sounds like you have successfully paired with your device and it shared the GATT services available on that device. Next steps would typically be `connect <device address>`. Then select GATT attribute and read or write.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with bluetooth?